# JpaSort.unsafe throwing Exception

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data

Using Spring Boot and Spring Data.
Using `JpaSort.unsafe` but getting Exception. 
Is this a known Spring issue? Hibernate/JPA issue?
Thanks.

Maven:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

Entity:

```
public class Simple {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    ...
}
```

Repository method:

```
public List<Simple> findAll(Sort sort);
```

SpringTestClass:

```
    list = simpleRepository.findAll(JpaSort.unsafe("LENGTH(firstName)"));
    assertEquals("firstName", list.get(0).getFirstName());
```

Exception:

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property LENGTH(firstName) found for type Simple!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case, adding `@Query` to repository class method helps solve this issue. I don't understand why. You can try if it helps you

```
@Query("SELECT s FROM Simple s")
```

Comment: save me hours+!

Comment: This is not worked with specifications: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26379522/can-i-combine-a-query-definition-with-a-specification-in-a-spring-data-jpa-repo

Answer (score 1):

This post here says you have to put parentheses around the string you are passing in. Maybe it applies here.

[How to sort projection by alias from SELECT clause in Spring Data JPA with pagination?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43993952/how-to-sort-projection-by-alias-from-select-clause-in-spring-data-jpa-with-pagin)