# Cannot use sort feature for pagination as my variable are in snake case [Spring-boot]

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm trying to implement pagination in my project. pagination is working fine if I am paginating result using pageOffset and pageSize. but when I try to use Sort feature it is unable to process the data and is throwing

> org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property request found for type InstituteSmsAllocationHistory!

I tried to change the variable name in many ways and found that if I keep name as "request id" then the error changes to

> org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property request id found for type InstituteSmsAllocationHistory! Did you mean 'request_id'?

but I dont know how to make it understand that I want it to sort by request_id

I don't want to change the structure of my project to camel case from snake case.

Please find my code below:
InstituteSmsAllocationHistory.java (Entity)

```
package com.proc.admin.rest.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.proc.common.entity.AuditableEntity;
import com.proc.common.entity.Institution;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Entity
@Table(name = "tab_inst_sms_allocation_hist")
@Getter
@Setter
public class InstituteSmsAllocationHistory extends AuditableEntity<String> implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4218076388772964964L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int               request_id;
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "institution_id")
    private Institution       institution_id;
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "sms_plan_id")
    private SMSPlanMaster     sms_plan_id;
    private int               sms_quota_allocated;
    private String            quota_type;
    private String            reason;
}
```

InstituteSmsAllocationHistoryController.java (Controller)

```
 @GetMapping(value = HISTORY + ALL)
    public ResponseEntity<PageResponseEntity<InstituteSmsAllocationHistory>> getSmsAllocationHistory(@RequestParam(defaultValue = "1") int pageOffset,
            @RequestParam(defaultValue = "10") int pageSize,
            @RequestParam(defaultValue = "request_id") String sortBy) {
        return RestResponseConverterUtil.sucess(smsPlanMasterService.getAllSmsHistory(pageOffset - 1, pageSize, sortBy));
    }
```

InstituteSmsAllocationHistoryServiceImpl.java (Service)

```
 @Override
    public PageResponseEntity<InstituteSmsAllocationHistory> getAllSmsHistory(int pageOffset, int pageSize, String sortBy) {
        Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pageOffset, pageSize, Sort.by("request_id"));
        Page<InstituteSmsAllocationHistory> page = instituteSmsAllocationHistoryDao.findAll(pageable);
        PageResponseEntity<InstituteSmsAllocationHistory> pageList = new PageResponseEntity<InstituteSmsAllocationHistory>(page.getContent(), ++pageOffset, pageSize, sortBy, page.getTotalElements());
        return pageList;
    }
```

Please let me know if you need anything other than this.

Thank you!

Comment: did you try with request__id with two underscore

Comment: @ShaileshChandra yes I tried request__id

Answer (score 0):

Why would you call your properties like that?

If you want to make snake case the default for column names, just use the appropriate [naming strategy](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-field-naming-spring-boot) (snake case *is* the default BTW). I'd strongly advise to use regular Java naming conventions, otherwise you might run into trouble later on.

As regards sorting, if all else fails, try using `JpaSort.unsafe(sortBy)`. Keep in mind that Spring Data will not validate the existence of the property in such a case - a misspelled property will only be recognized by the underlying DB when a query is attempted.

Comment: I cannot change the structure as I am not allowed to do so. also the error didn't go by using `JpaSort.unsafe(sortBy)` the error remained the same. I also read about [this] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43993952/how-to-sort-projection-by-alias-from-select-clause-in-spring-data-jpa-with-pagin but trying this didn't helped me.